# How big should be disk for SVN load

Tags: svn, size, restore, dump, disk

Our SVN server died and I need to restore repository to new server.

On old server our repository had about 1,5 TB, I have dump of the last revision that takes about 3,2 TB on network share. In new server I had two disk, 500GB with system and 4TB for SVN repository. I've created new repository, started loading dump using svnadmin, but after 16 hours I've got error that there is no space left.

Dump was created using command:

**svnadmin dump -r HEAD /opt/data/svn/repo_01 > /media/backup/dump**

I'm restoring it using command:

**svnadmin load --bypass-prop-validation /svn/repos/repo_01/ < /media/backup/dump** (old repo was running svn 1.5.6, I'm restoring to latest version)

And error is:

**editing path : projects/M-0578/tags/Weekly-Builts/CC9060_Week-0824-V149/Box/Application/CC9060/CC9060_loader.dxe ...svnadmin: E000028: Can't open file '/svn/repos/repo_01/db/transactions/0-0.txn/node._ava58.0.props': No space left on device**

I have following questions:

- Did anyone know how svnadmin load works?
- Is it unpacking files to some temporary location?
- How big should be disks for this repository?

Comment: Welcome to SO @Martin. I believe this message should be posted on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/). Please read the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) link to have a better idea for SO questions.

Comment: Hi, I've found some posts regarding SVN here, so I've added this question on SO.

Comment: Yes @Martin, you can post issues about SVN here, with no problem. I'm just saying that your question is not directly about SVN, but server configuration. For this reason is more suitable in Server Fault.

Comment: Thank for this information. I will ask on SF so.

Comment: @Tom svn questions are perfectly on topic here, AFAIK.

Comment: @bahrep, I've never said svn questions are off-topic, I just believe that this question, in its core, is not about svn, but about server configuration (dump restore, disk space, temporary location in the server - look at its tags). IMHO it suits better in SF and can even get an answer faster there . Also, [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page says itself - Don't ask: "Anything not directly related to writing computer programs". Anyway, it was just a suggestion.

Comment: @Tom the question is essentially about dump streams and how `svnadmin dump`, `svnadmin load` works with revision dump streams.

Comment: @martin how did you create the dump? Did you use `--deltas` option with `svnadmin dump`?

Comment: You should also specify the exact wordings of errors and exact commands you ran.

Answer (score 1):

You should find answers to your questions by reading [SVNBook | Migrating Repository Data Elsewhere](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate) chapter.

> Is it unpacking files to some temporary location?

Not really. There are temporary files for new revision in the target repository, but they should not be the cause to "out of space" errors, AFAIK.

> How big should be disks for this repository?

It's hard to predict without knowing the number of revisions and kind of data you store in the repositories. Moreover, we have to know the command that you used to generate the dump. Did you use [`--deltas`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svnadmin.html#svn.ref.svnadmin.sw.deltas) option?

What is the exact wording of the error that you were getting?

---

The dump files contain revision dump stream. These files are usually much larger than the repository itself on disk. The dump streams contain full-text representation of every revision and do not use any special space-saving techniques, by default.

However, there is a chance that the dump file was generated with [`--deltas`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svnadmin.html#svn.ref.svnadmin.sw.deltas) option. In such case the dump stream does not contain full-text representation of revisions. Instead of this, it contains compressed binary deltas between revisions. In some cases, such dump file could be smaller than the repository on disk.

I can't tell why you get the error, because I don't known the error you get, the command you run, how you generated the dump etc. BTW, there is a chance that this repository was larger than ~1.5TB.

Comment: I was dumping only head revision. I'm getting error: * editing path : projects/M-0578/tags/Weekly-Builts/CC9060_Week-0824-V149/Box/Application/CC9060/CC9060_loader.dxe ...svnadmin: E000028: Can't open file '/svn/repos/repo_01/db/transactions/0-0.txn/node._ava58.0.props': No space left on device. I'm restoring repo using command svnadmin load --bypass-prop-validation /svn/repos/repo_01/ < /media/backup/dump